[MSSQL][REPLICATION][AVAILABILITY GROUP] Publisher is pointing to the secondary (not readable)
I have a new client with replication that doesn't sync anything.
The log reader agent status windows shows this error :

The target database, '', is participating in an availability group and is currently not accessible for queries. Either data movement is suspended or the availability replica is not enabled for read access. To allow read-only access to this and other databases in the availability group, enable read access to one or more secondary availability replicas in the group. For more information, see the ALTER AVAILABILITY GROUP statement in SQL Server Books Online.

Here is the infrastructure in place :

AG01 (NO DATA LOSS)

NODE1 (PRIMARY)
NODE2
Database : MyDatabasePublisher
Database : MyDatabaseSubscriber


AG02 (NO DATA LOSS)

NODE3 (PRIMARY)
NODE4
Database : distribution



To make it clear :

The distribution database is on its own AG with its own dedicated nodes.
The publisher and the subscriber are on the same AG.

I connect to NODE1 to validate that all databases are read/write and I find all the publications and subscriptions on the replication node in SSMS. I also have all the jobs related to the replication on that NODE1.
When I open the replication monitor from NODE1, it is empty.
Now if I connect to NODE2 I don't have anything in the replication node nor in the jobs.
However the replication monitor displays all the publishers, all in RED with the error aforementioned.
On MyDatabasePublisher I check the content of the tables :

dbo.MSreplication_objects
dbo.MSreplication_subscriptions
dbo.MSsubscription_agents

Each of these tables have a publisher table that is : NODE2
I'm trying hard to understand what is going on however I feel like I need some replication experts to explain that to me because at this point, it doesn't make any sense to me. I think that something has been missed during the configuration of this replication.
Help please !!
